# JQVMAP : mapping after zoom issue

Tags: jquery, jqvmap

http://s16.postimg.org/99hve381x/anatomy.png

I'm trying to zoom after clicking on the path,is it possible to allow another mapping after zooming ?

This is the code i'm trying,

```
var showAll = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
    {
        map: 'male_anatomy',
        backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
        borderColor: '#818181',
        borderOpacity: .50,
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#f4f3f0',
        enableZoom: true,
        hoverColor: '#c9dfaf',
        hoverOpacity: null,
        normalizeFunction: 'linear',
        scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
        selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
        selectedRegion: null,
        showTooltip: true,
        onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
            $('path').each(function () {
                if (showAll) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            if (showAll) { showAll = false; } else { showAll = true; }

            var id = '#jqvmap1_' + code;
            $(id).show();
        }
    });
    });
```